# How to get the latest message offset from the FlinkKafkaConsumer?

Tags: apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I am using FlinkKafkaConsumer  to consume the data from kafka? but I am not able to get the latest offset from he data received. How to do it in flink?.Could anyone guide me in this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a custom deserialziation schema called `KeyedDeserializationSchema` to access the offset for each message.

The `deserialize()` method has an argument where the framework passes you the offset for each message.